# Why won't my Fabric.js canvas work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, fabricjs

The link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UTf87/
for some reason my canvas won't display the rectangle that it's supposed to, any clue why?

hmtl:

```
<div id="CanvasContainer">
    <canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#CanvasContainer {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    height: 519px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    background: black;
}
#Canvas {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
}
```

javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('CanvasContainer');
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        fill: 'red',
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        angle: 45
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
}
```

Comment: I see a green rectangle... what is it you are seeing or not?

Comment: Do you know what Fabricjs is? there is supposed to be a red rectangle at 100 left 100 top that you can drag, scale and rotate. There has to be something wrong with  the code because i've got it to wokr before

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/bGRCL/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('Canvas');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    angle: 45
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

Your window.onload was not required because of the jsfiddle options that were selected, so the function was never called.

Also, you were selecting the CanvasContainer instead of the Canvas itself.
Instead of :

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('CanvasContainer');
```

Use:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('Canvas');
```

Comment: If you are updating or forking, the url changes, make sure you provide the updated URL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41219/discussion-between-gobo-and-user2961869)

Comment: You might want to brush up a bit more on your programming, the problem here is outside the scope of this question.  You are using jquery code but haven't included the jquery source.

Comment: i have, just the fiddle doesn't want the header.. here's a link to EVERYTHING. http://jsfiddle.net/a7ZSG/9/ sry for being so ignorent